# Is there an easy way to load a propertygrid with 300+ properties?

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I am looking to create a rather extensive property grid to include up to 400 assignable properties.

Based on what I see here from MSDN:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    private bool saveOnClose = true;
    private string greetingText = "Welcome to your application!";
    private int itemsInMRU = 4;
    private int maxRepeatRate = 10;
    private bool settingsChanged = false;
    private string appVersion = "1.0";

    public bool SaveOnClose
    {
        get { return saveOnClose; }
        set { saveOnClose = value;}
    }
    public string GreetingText
    {
        get { return greetingText; }
        set { greetingText = value; }
    }
    public int MaxRepeatRate
    {
        get { return maxRepeatRate; }
        set { maxRepeatRate = value; }
    }
    public int ItemsInMRUList
    {
        get { return itemsInMRU; }
        set { itemsInMRU = value; }
    }
    public bool SettingsChanged
    {
        get { return settingsChanged; }
        set { settingsChanged = value; }
    }
    public string AppVersion
    {
        get { return appVersion; }
        set { appVersion = value; }
    }
}
```

This method would take ages and seems very inefficient.  Am I missing a better way to populate a long list of properties?

I do have all the data in an .xls if there is a roundabout way of scraping the data from the sheets.

Comment: *Attributes* or *properties*? What doesn't work? 400 properties is ok (I have twice less, but with property localization, custom editors, attributes and a lot of reflection things and nothing *"take ages and seems very inefficient"*).

Comment: Edited for properties.  I was just thinking there had to be a better way to create the class than type 400 setters individually for every property name/description/value etc.

Comment: Looking into these custom editors though.

Comment: You are using c# 6.0. Then [auto-property with field initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) should be the best for you, e.g. `public string AppVersion {get; set;} = "1.0"` . I don't think you want it any shorter (as you may want to use attributes, e.g. `[DefaultValue]` for `PropertyGrid` itself).

Comment: What real problem do you face? What have you tested?

Comment: There are usability guidelines for this sort of UI, also used on this website.  You can get a user to look through a list with 30 items, if it matters then you can push it to 50.  A program that displays 400 needs a good uninstaller.   This is supposed to hurt.  Take a look at Visual Studio's Tools > Options dialog for a decent approach.